# PhP - how to get the name of these objects

Tags: php, json

I'm new to PHP and I'm having trouble to figure out how to achieve one simple thing. I'm making a method which will return an array with key and value matching a JSON schema to a JSON data. By the way is there something that does it already?

Back to my question: I have this schema:

```
$demoSchema = '
    {
        "type":"object",
        "properties":{
            "firstName":{"title":"First name", "type":"string", "pattern":"^[a-z]+$"},
            "lastName":{"title":"Last name", "type":"string","pattern":"^[a-z]+$"},
            "age":{"title":"Age", "description":"Age in years","type":"integer","minimum":1},
            "country":{"title":"Country", "type":"string", "enum":["Canada","US"]},
            "address":{"title":"Address", "type":"string"},
            "postalCode":{"title":"Postal Code", "type":"string"},
            "city":{"title":"City", "type":"string"},
            "province_ca":{"title":"Province", "type":"string", "enum":["Ontario","Quebec"]},
            "province_us":{"title":"State", "type":"string"}
        },
        "required":["firstName","lastName","country"]
    }
';
```

Here is how I transform it in an array:

```
$obj_schema = (array)json_decode($demoSchema);
```

My problem by now is that I can't get the name of the objects within the properties objects: `firstName`, `lastName`, etc.

How can I get them? When I do this loop I can get the properties inside the object, which I need as well:

```
foreach ($obj_schema["properties"]  as $item){
    echo($item->title);
}
```

But I can't get the `firstName`, `lastName`, etc strings. How can I do that?

Comment: if you print_r($obj_schema) what's you get?

Comment: `foreach (... as $key => $item)`...?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($obj_schema["properties"]  as $property => $item){
    echo($item->title);
    echo 'Property Name:'. $property;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way (convert the hole data to an array first):

```
$obj_schema = json_decode($demoSchema,true);#<--NoteA
foreach ($obj_schema["properties"]  as $property => $item){
  echo($property."  ".$item['title']);
}
```

NoteA: `true`  convert the hole given data into arrays

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to cast into array, because by `json_decode($demoSchema)` you are getting stdClass object. So you could do only:

```
$obj_schema = json_decode($demoSchema);
```

and then fetch first name:

```
echo $obj_schema->properties->firstName->title;
```

or you can get all of them with foreach:

```
foreach ($obj_schema->properties as $item){
    echo $item->title;
}
```